# How to correctly set state value of React component to an array of JSON objects?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to set state of a React component to be an array of JSON objects.

However, I get the following error:

Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name, age}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

What is the correct way to do this ?

```
class SQLPane extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      value: 'Default SQL query string.',
      result: [],
      error: ''
    }
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  }

  handleSubmit() {
    var x = this.state.result
    var y = {name: 'A', age: 5}
    var z = [...x, y]
    console.log(x)
    console.log(y)
    console.log(z)
    this.setState({result: z})
  }

  // Remaining code...

}
```

Comment: The error is saying something you have in your `render` method, which you did not provide in your code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error message, I suspect you have something like this in your render function. I think the way you update array in `this.setState` is correct.

```
render() {
  const obj = this.state;
  return (
    ....
    <div>
     {{obj}} {/* single curly bracket should be used here */}
    </div>
    ....
  )
}
```

Comment: That solved it. Thanks! I was in my render function displaying {this.state.result} but now made it {JSON.stringify(this.state.result)} which solved the problem.